# How to stretch an empty element horizontally

Tags: css, html

I am trying to achieve an effect in HTML + CSS like this

```
_____________________[           Some Div             ]
```

The `____` is a `border-bottom`. The `Div` to the right of it shouldn't have the border. I want this border to stretch as much as possible, so that together they occupy the width of the parent. I am trying to avoid any fixed spacing layout.

I tried using a table with `width:100%`:

```
<table style="width:100%"><tbody><tr>
    <td id="borderDiv"></td>
    <td id="contentDiv">Some Div</td>
</tr><?tbody></table>
```

The extra space goes to the second `td` instead of the first one. I also tried floating the content div to the right:

```
<div>
    <div id="contentDiv" style="float:right">Some Div</div>
    <div id="borderDiv"></div>
</div>
```

But the div with the border now fills up the entire space of the parent. Couldn't figure out a way to constraint it to the leftover space.

Comment: HRJ, what exactly is "as much space as needed" supposed to mean (in your comment to Brian's post)? What are the contents of the right div/td? Text only? Pictures?

Comment: @TomBartel My first comment to Brian's post was hasty. Please ignore it.

Comment: Yep, got it. Still, question nicely put, +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question and I know the HTML + CSS purists are going to hate me for this but can't you do the following:

```
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000; width: 100%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><nobr>my content</nobr></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If the second column has a specific width that you want you can specify that and remove the `<nobr>` tags and end up with something like:

```
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000; width: 100%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 200px">my content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This makes the second td to squeeze in width. I want it to take as much space as needed, and let the first td fill up the leftover.

Comment: Sorry, I had missed the <nobr> tag in your answer! I had never seen it before. It works perfectly fine. Thnx much

Comment: No problem. Remember that if you want the second column to take up multiple lines you will probably want to specify a width for that column and remove the `<nobr>` tags.

Comment: Found out that the purist alternative to `<nobr>` would be to add the CSS property: `white-space:nowrap`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
     <div id="contentDiv" style="float:right; width:30%">Some Div</div>
     <div id="borderDiv" style="margin-right: 30%"></div>
</div>
```

Floats are required to have a width so that's how I'd approach it.

This might work, but need more info about how you are dealing with the height. If it's fixed for example just make the float a bit taller.

```
<div>
     <div id="contentDiv" style="float:right;background:white;white-space:nowrap></div>
     <div id="borderDiv" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Gazzer, but as I mentioned, I am trying to avoid a fixed-width solution.

Comment: How are you controlling the height? You can give the contentDiv a background color and it'll cover the border on the bottom of the second div and use white-space:nowrap while removing the 30% in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

The purist alternative to Brian's solution, using CSS properties:

```
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000; width: 100%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="white-space:nowrap">my content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```